# How to add the key to an object added to a node in angularfire 2 version 5

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I used to be able to add the key to an object itself in angularfire2 v.4.x like this:

```
addMatchToDb(match: any){
    let ref = this.db.object('matches/');
    let matchId = this.matches.push(match).key;
    let updates = {};
    updates['/matches/' + matchId + '/id'] = matchId;
    updates['/matches/' + matchId + '/matchCreated'] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }
```

Since I get an error

> error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable'<'any'>'

, I thought about refactoring to:

```
addMatchToDb(match: any){
    let ref = this.db.object('matches/');
    let matchId = ref.update(match);
  }
```

but now I have no way of adding the key as an id or the timestamp. Any suggestions given the new changes with version 5?

Update: some details about this.matches:

```
export class DatabaseService {
  matches:Observable<any>;
  weightClasses:Observable<any>;
  giRanks:Observable<any>;
  noGiRanks:Observable<any>;
  ageClasses:Observable<any>;
  users:Observable<any>;
  currentUser:Observable<any>;
  moves:Observable<any>;
  retrievedMatch:Observable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private textTransformationService: TextTransformationService) {
    this.matches = db.list<Match>('/matches').valueChanges();
    this.weightClasses = db.list<string>('/weightClasses').valueChanges();
    this.giRanks = db.list<string>('/giRanks').valueChanges();
    this.noGiRanks = db.list<string>('/noGiRanks').valueChanges();
    this.ageClasses = db.list<string>('/ageClasses').valueChanges();
    this.users = db.list<User>('/users').valueChanges();
    this.moves = db.list<string>('/moves').valueChanges(); //TODO maybe JSON?
  }
```

Comment: How have you defined `matches` ?

Comment: As in, is the Match model fleshed out? Yes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking of `this.matches`. Is it defined with AngularFireList<any> ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Added details above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sur but Your push has to be done on `db.list<Match>('/matches')` and not  `db.list<Match>('/matches').valueChanges();`

So you can add the type AngularFireList to your variable `db.list<Match>('/matches')` and get push/update/remove methods

Comment: Wom wom. Thanks, @Wandrille